# Is is thread-safe to copy/modify a copy of an STL container?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I have a `std::map` that is going to be modified from multiple threads, and I have a mutex to lock these writes. However, the map must occasionally be used during a long-running operation, and it would not be good to hold the lock during this entire operation, blocking all of those writes.

I have two questions about this:

- Is it thread-safe to perform that operation on a copy of the map while other threads are writing to the original?
- Is it thread-safe to copy the map while other threads are mutating it?

For example:

```
class Foo {
    void writeToMap(Bar &bar, Baz &baz) {
        // lock mutex
        map[bar] = baz;
        // unlock mutex
    }

    std::map<Bar, Baz> getMapCopy() {
        // lock mutex (Is this necessary?)
        std::map<Bar, Baz> copy (map);
        // unlock mutex
        return copy;
    }

    std::map<Bar, Baz> map;
};

void expensiveOperation(Foo &f) {
    std::map<Bar, Baz> mapCopy = f.getMapCopy();
    // Can I safely read mapCopy?
}
```

Comment: You are returning a reference to a local variable. This does not work. If you return by value it will be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in that code, as you return a reference to a local variable. This locla variable will be destructed once the function returns, and you now have a reference to a destructed object.

If you want to return a *copy* then you have to return *by value*, so it would be e.g.

```
std::map<Bar, Baz> getMapCopy() {
    return map;
}
```

And if you use the mutexes and locks from the [C++11 standard thread library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) you don't need an explicit unlock, the mutex will be unlocked with the destruction of the lock.

Comment: Oops, thanks! So if I return by value, the copy I get can be safely read while the member is modified?

Comment: Awesome. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Is creating the copy thread-safe? Do I not need to hold the lock when I create it?

Comment: @Tiki : "*Is creating the copy thread-safe?*" No, you need to hold the lock for that.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the copy operation itself is not thread safe, the issue being atomicity of copying 64-bit values. You copy the first 4 bytes, while the second 4 is being modified by another thread leaving you with inconsistent 8 bytes.

Please have a look here: [Is copy thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688107/is-copy-thread-safe)

If you manage to create a consistent copy, however, I do not see why not...